# Docusign UpdateRecipients

Tags: docusignapi

Our application creates a draft envelope from a template using the API with 2 roles.

rolename: "signer1"
"recipientId":"1",
    "roleName":"signer1",
    "routingOrder":"1",
    "email":"email1",
    "name":"name1"

rolename: "signer2"
"recipientId":"2",
    "roleName":"signer2",
    "routingOrder":"2",
    "email":"email2",
    "name":"name2"

The draft creates properly and I can send this out as is.

The question is, if I want to update one of the recipients via API before sending, what field does docusign use to know which recipient you are trying to update?

e.g. I want to change the email address of signer1

I hope the question is clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

To modify an existing recipient from a Draft envelop, you need to use the "recipeintId" to refer to a specific Recipient and then enter the details you wish to modify in your PUT call.
Below you will find an example when I modifying recipientId 1 and I am giving him a new name and email address.

Note: I am using the X-DocuSign-Authentication header in the example for simplicity instead for security measure the bearer token should be used.

Doc: [Link to DocuSign Documentation](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Modify%20or%20Correct%20and%20Resend%20Recipient%20Information.htm%3FTocPath%3DREST%2520API%2520References%7C_____79)

```
PUT https://{server}/restapi/{apiVersion}/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients

X-DocuSign-Authentication: <DocuSignCredentials><Username>{name}</Username><Password>{password}</Password><IntegratorKey>{integrator_key}</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
{
 "signers" :
 [
   {
     "email": "john.doe@comapany.com",
     "name": "John Doe",
     "recipientId": "1"
    }
 ]
}
```

To collect the recipiendId of your envelop you can use. The GET request with the similar URL

```
GET https://{server}/restapi/{apiVersion}/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients
```

Comment: I have not tried this yet since I have placed the project in the back log for a while.  I will try this though and if it works, I'll give you a vote up. Thanks!